# Should scales start on 4th natural?

Tags: scales

The Pythagorean system of tuning produces, via succeeding 3/2 multiples of a base note (e.g., C), the following set of successive tone ratios:

C to D: 9/8
D to E: 9/8
E to F: 256/243
F to G: 9/8
G to A: 9/8
A to B: 9/8
B to C: 256/243

However, in order to obtain the value for F, one must either drop down a fourth (i.e., multiply C by 2/3) or continue around the circle of fifths for eleven steps.  Would it instead make sense to begin the scale at F or, if it begins at C, to end it on F-sharp?  In other words, would it be better, on a keyboard, to start the scale with four white notes rather than the current three?  If so, the ratios would be as follows:

9/8
9/8
9/8
256/243
9/8
9/8
256/243

This seems to be where the math leads.  Any thoughts are welcome.  Thanks!

-Burch

Comment: As I see it, we have no scientific explanation for why our scale-degree 4 is (in C) F and not F#. I'll be interested to see what answers come up here!

Comment: @Richard - C>F# is the dreaded tritone, quite dissonant. That's probably a good enough reason in itself to not be the 4th degree of a major scale...  Music seems to work better, and is more listenable when the notes don't jar. Although the aug4 is useful to modulate to the dominant.

Comment: @Tim Yes, but C to B is also dissonant, and we don't seem to make a fuss about that. I still don't think we have a real *scientific* explanation; "Music seems to work better, and is more listenable when the notes don't jar" unfortunately doesn't meet that requirement.

Comment: @Tim "C>F# is the dreaded tritone, quite dissonant" So is F>B, but nobody has tried to exclude that from a major scale, AFAIK. Anyway, the OP is talking about *Pythagorean* tuning, which makes tritones a different interval from equal temperament. In some temperaments tritones are not dissonant at all!

Comment: "This seems to be where the math leads." - try listening to the result rather than playing with math. You might find that a "major third" of 81/64 sounds pretty rough before you even get to your version of a tritone.

Comment: I wonder if Tim is on to something. F to B is dissonant, but maybe it's not as noticeable as C to F#, because the latter involves the root itself. C to B seems less dissonant too. There might be a scientific explanation lurking somewhere behind what naturally/intuitively sounds good.

Comment: @Burch, I don't see why the math favors F# over F. On the circle of fifths, isn't F only one step away from C, whereas F# is as far away from C as is possible (6 steps away)? Or are you saying it would be more consistent for the notes of C major to require only *clockwise* movement around the circle: | C | G D A E B F# rather than F | C | G D A E B. Couldn't we just as easily say that the math favors notes *closer* on the circle to the root? That would make the preferred scale, in C: Eb Bb F | C | G D A. This cuts out notes like E and B which are farther from C on the circle of fifths.

Comment: Perhaps I'm trying to make the point that you've proposed a value judgment because you selected one mathematical pattern when multiple are available. The math doesn't contain value judgements like "the scale *should* only include clockwise movement around the circle of fifths" or "the scale *should* only include notes closer on the circle to the root." We could come up with other similar mathematical patterns, but saying that one is better than another is a subjective value judgment. It is still a very interesting question though, "why do we prefer F as the fourth over F# in a major scale?"

Comment: Isn't this essentially the idea presented by George Russell in [The Lydian Chromatic Concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lydian_Chromatic_Concept_of_Tonal_Organization)? I believe he took fifths to be fundamental, and then noted that the Lydian mode can be constructed by stacking fifths.

Comment: All, thanks for the helpful feedback! David hit the nail on the head with his reference to Russell's Lydian Chromatic Concept of Tonal Organization, which is new to me. Per the Wikipedia entry: "Russell believed that dominant function was the driving force behind all harmonic motion. Russell focuses on the Lydian mode because it can be built with fifths. For instance, to construct a C lydian scale one could list the first seven tones on the circle of fifths starting with C, the desired Lydian Tonic. This process would yield C, G, D, A, E, B, F♯." Thanks again! -Burch

Comment: The bottom line is that however you slice the math, if you adopt the basic idea of Pythagorean tuning to Just intervals with small integer ratios, somewhere you have to "lose" a factor of 81/80 to close the octave correctly. The "traditional" way to do this is have two different sizes of whole tones, 9/8 and 10/9, not to get rid of the perfect 4ths and 5ths between C and F.

Answer (score 1):

What would be the advantage?

F# is the tritone in C, which sounds quite dissonant to most people, so that's a pretty good reason, possibly the primary one.

Keep in mind that you're talking about using the Lydian mode instead of the Ionian mode or major scale, and some pieces do use the Lydian mode. The Ionian mode/major scale is more popular, probably because of the way it sounds.

Personally, I love the fourth scale degree being 5 half steps above the tonic, and I like having a whole step between the fourth and fifth degrees.